# Condicional con variables obtenidas de un archivo txt en python

Tags: python

Tengo dos funciones, una que lee un archivo txt y asigna a cada linea una variable. y otra donde quiero hacer un condicional usando estas variables. Sin embargo, parece no entrar en el condicional a pesar de cumplirse.

```
Compuesto = None

def Leer():
    w = open('Variables.txt', 'r')
    global Compuesto
    Compuesto = w.readline()
    Presion1 = w.readline()
    Presion2 = w.readline()
    Temperatura1 = w.readline()
    Temperatura2 = w.readline()
    Propiedad = w.readline()
    w.close()
    print(Compuesto)


def Condicion():

        if Compuesto == 'Compuesto b':
            PresionCritica = 2
            print(PresionCritica)

        else:
            print(Compuesto)


Leer()
Condicion()
```

Se que no estoy usando las demás variables pero es para aplicar al primer caso.  Al compilar resulta:
Compuesto b
Compuesto b.
Entonces efectivamente la variable se llama Compuesto b, pero no entra en la condición. Ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

Tenemos el siguiente archivo:

```
Compuesto B
45
35
Temperatura 10
Temperatura 20
Temperatura 30
```

en Python:

```
def Leer():
    w = open('test.txt', 'r')
    Compuesto = w.readline()
    Presion1 = w.readline()
    Condicion(Compuesto)

def Condicion(Compuesto):
  print Compuesto
  if Compuesto.strip() == 'Compuesto B':
    print "excelente"

Leer()
```

como vez la funcion leer se encarga de leer el archivo asigno a variables y acto seguido invoco a una funcion **Condicion** la misma que hace o hará las validaciones pertinentes, le paso como parametro lo que necesito en este caso Compuesto.

Tambien debes tomar en cuenta que al leer un archivo tambien lee con espacios en blanco por lo cual para eliminarlos y coincidan en la condicion use esto:

```
Compuesto.strip()
```

el resultado:

[image: result]

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Answer (score 0):

He modificado tu script para que no use una variable global (no recomendado). Lo importante es la linea `return Compuesto` en `Leer()` y que ahora `Condicion()` acepta un argumento que es usado en el if.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


def Leer():
    with open('Variables.txt', 'r') as w:
        Compuesto = w.readline()
    return Compuesto


def Condicion(comp):
    if comp == 'Compuesto b':
        PresionCritica = 2
        print(PresionCritica)
    else:
        print(comp)


def main():
    r = Leer().strip()
    Condicion(r)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```